# Redirect `csplit` output to a pager instead of creating files

Tags: linux, csplit

I am using `scplit` to split a large file where the spitting pattern is `--`. My goal is to redirect all the splits into a pager rather than creating files. In the pager, I want to be able to watch one split at a time. The command to split the file turns out to be quite easy:

```bash
csplit -s --suppress-matched test.txt '/--/' '{*}'
```

But I do not know to to redirect the outputs to a pager. Is that possible?

Comment: `csplit -s --suppress-matched test.txt '/--/' '{*}' | less` (or `|more`)? You may need `csplit ... 2>&1 | less`). OR I'm not understanding yourr prroblem. Doesn't `csplit` create files? Do you expect to see the contents of the files? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter "Doesn't csplit create files?" Yes, and I it not my goal. My goal is to redirect the splits to a pager rather than creating files

Comment: @shellter piping it to `less` I get an empty file and the files are created regardless....

Comment: It's hard to understand why you want to do this. Are you experimenting, or do you have a real need. I you want to see your file in chunks, maybe  somthing like `awk -v splitSz=100 '{if (!(NR % splitSz)) {print "\n\n"}1' myFilet | less` gives you what you want. This should put in 2 blank lines ever 100 lines of input, but print the complete contents of the file to the pager. Good luck.